# 403 error on a publicly available server on my pc and ec2 instance, but not on my developer and friends pc

Tags: http, http-status-code-403

My developer made a program that makes a GET request to a publicly accessible server. When he runs locally on his mac laptop and windows pc, the program works great. When I run the program on my windows laptop and my windows pc I receive a 403 error. Additionally when the ec2 instance runs the program, it also receives a 403 error. When my friend runs the program on his windows pc it works great. The only difference between me, my developer, my friend, and the ec2 instance is our geography. I'm in the same state as the ec2 instance and the publicly accessible server we are working with. My developer and friend both live in different states, respectively. This may or may not be important, but I am able to connect and download the files on my computer from my browser.

We have tried connecting to a vpn and running the program that way, but I'm still receiving a 403 status. We also set up a simple python script with the requests module to make a GET request to the url. In addition we copied the request headers found after successfully downloading the files via web broswer. This also resulted in a 403 status. We tried using curl to make a GET request via powershell, which also failed.